# JavaScript regular expression to catch [boxes]

Tags: javascript, regex

So I'm using urban dictionary api and their terms can link to others using [term] with api you get the boxes i thought of making them actually hyperlink in markdown, i.e [term](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=term) so i tried to make a replace regex to do it i did fine so far except that it doesn't work when the box has more than one word like [space words] i keep trying to find a good regex to match that but it endsup matching the whole string here's the regular expression i used which did fine but not get spaces

```
"example [string] with [some] boxes".replace(/(\[(\S+)\])/ig, "$1(https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=$2)");
```

Comment: Try `/(\[([^\][]+)\])/g`, e.g. `.replace(/\[([^\][]+)\]/g, "$&(https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=$1)")`. BTW, shouldn't the spaces be replaced with `+`? Then check out `.replace(/\[([^\][]+)\]/g, (x,y) =>  x + "(https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=" + y.replace(/\s+/g, "+") + ")")`

Comment: Oh that works, thanks

Comment: Replacing your `(\S+)` with `([\w\s]+)` works fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `/(\[([^\][]+)])/g` regex and replace with `"$&(https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=$1)"`:

```js
console.log(
      "example [string] with [space words] boxes".replace(
         /\[([^\][]+)]/g, "$&(https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=$1)")
    );
```

If the spaces should be replaced with `+` you may use

```js
console.log(
  "example [string] with [space words] boxes".replace(
     /\[([^\][]+)]/g, (x,y) => 
     x + "(https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=" + y.replace(/\s+/g, "+") + ")")
);
```

Note that you needn't enclose the whole pattern into a capturing group, you can always access the whole match value with the help of `$&` placeholder from the  replacement pattern. Hence, only one `(...)` in the suggested pattern.

**Pattern details**

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `([^\][]+)` - Capturing group 1: any one or more chars other than `[` and `]` (note that `[` does not have to be escaped inside a character class, but `]` must)
- `]`  - a `]` char (note that outside of a character class `]` does not have to be escaped).